# Using Views module (Drupal 7) to display php array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, filter, view

I have a php array (let's call it $people) that I specifically created from LinkedIn API. The fact is I don't want to record it in my own database due to the huge amount of data and I don't want to use a Cron to update results.

So, the problem is **I want to display results from my php array in a filterable/sortable table**. Notice: I can parameter this array to catch results from a START parameter with a COUNT parameter; this is mandatory for the pagination.

How to use Views module of Drupal 7 to do that? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the exact question but assuming you want to display some data in a paginated table, I can give you some hints. You can try the [theme_table()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) to render a paginated table. Here is rough sample code https://drupal.org/node/156863

Integration with views in a relatively complex task. Easiest way is to go with https://drupal.org/project/data. But if you want integrate more, then start with the [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7)